# collection in array query brand

Tags: mongodb

I have a query that has a **query** user and **brands**. So how can I brands **"nokia"** I get those

```
db = Connection().mydb

db.users.find()
```

the query:

```
{u'username': u'mack', u'brand': [{u'name': u'nike'}, {u'name': u'adidas'}] }

{u'username': u'siyve', u'brand': [{u'name': u'nokia'}, {u'name': u'casio'}] }

{u'username': u'seylim', u'brand': [{u'name': u'nokia'}, {u'name': u'casio'}] }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
db.users.find({ "brand.name": "nokia" })
```